# The Return statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

Assuming *A.sql* contains the following code, then second Select query won’t be executed due to Return statement:

```
select *
from Films;

return;

select *
from Films;
```

If *A.sql* was called inside a stored procedure *SP1* or batch *B1*, then RETURN would transfer control back to *SP1* or *B1*, respectively. But assuming *A.sql* isn’t called from inside of another object ( batch, SP, UDF … ), to what is control transferred to ( in other words, where does RETURN return to )?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998(SQL.90).aspx) returns from a query or procedure.
>   RETURN is immediate and complete and
>   can be used at any point to exit from
>   a procedure, batch, or statement
>   block. Statements that follow RETURN
>   are not executed.

So this just means that if there is no outer frame, execution simply ends.